# How to solve or debug that IPyWidgets are just partially shown?

Tags: python, macos, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I have just installed Jupyter Notebooks and a new Python environment using `venv` on my vanilla Macbook (I have not used Jupyter on this hardware before). Now I am running the Jupyter Notebook, that is using IPyWidgets as input controls, and recognized that only some of the widgets are shown.

A minimal example, which reproduces the behaviour on my machine:

```
import ipywidgets
display(
    ipywidgets.Combobox(description='test1'), 
    ipywidgets.Checkbox(description='test2'), 
    ipywidgets.Button(description='test3')
)
```

This is what the output looks on my machine:

[image]

And this is what it's supposed to look like (taken on another machine):

[image]

As you can see, on my machine only the button is displayed (which also means that `ipywidgets` is essentially working). As no error is shown, I do not have any clue where to start debugging this nor how to solve it and would appreciate advice on how to continue from here.

I have already tried different browsers (namely Chrome & Safari) without any effect on the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I initially installed Jupyter on the main environment and then created a virtual environment using `venv`. Obviously this has caused issues since the problem is gone after installing Jupyter into the same `venv`.